# Web Api endpoint complex object vs simple flat object best practice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

What would be the best way to offer a resource in ASP.NET Web Api? Are their any references or guidelines for this?

Lets say for example we have a person.

**Option 1:**

```
{
  "Personalia": {
    "CitizenServiceNumber": "23443342",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Web",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "DateOfBirth": "1965-02-16",
  },
  "Spouse": {
    "FirstName": "Emily",
    "LastName": "Web",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "DateOfBirth": "1968-02-16"
  },
  "Address": {
    "HouseNumber": "565",
    "Street": "Somewherestreet"
  }
}
```

- **Pro** It's easy to read
- **Con** We need multiple classes/models (Person, Personalia, Spouse, Address) to get/post/put a single person

**Option 2:**

```
{
    "CitizenServiceNumber": "23443342",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Web",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "DateOfBirth": "1965-02-16",
    "SpouseFirstName": "Emily",
    "SpouseLastName": "Web",
    "SpouseGender": "Female",
    "SpouseDateOfBirth": "1968-02-16",
    "HouseNumber": "565",
    "Street": "Somewherestreet"
}
```

- **Pro** We just need 1 class
- **Con** It's less readable/structured, especially for classes with more data

This is ofcourse a fairly simple example but the question remains the same with a more complex class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with the first option. You shouldn't be worried about having lots of objects. Those are called view models and are used exactly for this purpose. In addition to that you could reuse some parts of those objects in other parts of your API where you might need things like addresses, persons, ...

If you look more carefully at this JSON string you don't actually need `Person`, `Personalia` and `Spouse` objects to map this structure. A single Person object would be enough.

For example here's how the view model that your API controller action takes might look like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public PersonViewModel Personalia { get; set; }
    public PersonViewModel Spouse { get; set; }
    public AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello Darin, I understand that I could make 1 Person class/viewmodel which exposes multiple objects. My concern is mostly about the relying party that wants to add a new person by using the API. In this scenario they still need a person/spouse/address and person. Just to add 1 person. (Lets say we want to save more personalia data about the person then about the spouse, so they don't fit in a single class). Would you, from a relying party point off view still have the same opinion?

Comment: If you need more data you simply derive from the PersonViewModel class and add the new properties.

Comment: I agree with you that if I was just making a MVC application myself this would be the best approach. But do you think this is also the best approach if we have parties that rely on the data and need to get/post/put it. Now they also need to make this classes, what's your opinion about this relying party point of view.

Comment: What does clients have to do with your Web API? You should design your Web API so that it works with JSON objects that are readable and understandable. Don't forget that a client could be written in any language, not just .NET and there are languages which doesn't even have the notion of classes. For example if you are calling your Web API using javascript and AJAX requests. And if the clients that will be consuming your API will be written in .NET, well, you have JSON serializers that would happily serialize anonymous objects into the desired JSON string so you don't need to bother.

Comment: Say a relying party wanted to add a person using Microsoft ASP.NET Web Api Client Libraries, like this: client.PostAsJsonAsync("htt//api/person", person); here person simply is a object of type Person. When I make a person more complex, it also becomes more complex for the relying party, my users. PS. I just see your update, I agree on the other languages like javascript. But I guess most users will be using .NET. Could you maybe show me a example/point me to a link on how to serialize such an anonymous object into the desired JSON string?

Comment: If you have a .NET client you could share the view models between the server and the client. If you don't want to share them you could use anonymous objects on the client.